# Transpose data while joining in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, transpose

I have the following two tables:

Describe **Futures**;

```
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field  | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID     | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| DATE   | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| NAME   | varchar(10)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| VALUE  | decimal(4,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Describe **Index**;

```
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| DATE  | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| VALUE | decimal(4,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

In table **Futures** I have data like this:

```
2018-06-13 AUG 2018 20.10
2018-06-13 SEP 2018 21.10

2018-06-14 AUG 2018 20.25
2018-06-14 SEP 2018 21.35
...
```

*(Normaly I would select * from Futures where NAME = "AUG 2018" order by DATE to see what AUG 2018 data was during the days)*

In table **Index**, I have simple data like this:

```
2018-06-13 32.10
2018-06-14 32.50
...
```

Now, I'd like to generate as simple a report like this:

```
+------------+-------+----------+----------+
| DATE       | INDEX | AUG 2018 | SEP 2018 |
+------------+-------+----------+----------+
| 2018-06-13 | 32.10 | 20.10    | 21.10    |
| 2018-06-14 | 32.50 | 20.25    | 21.35    |
+------------+-------+----------+----------+
```

*(**Index** and **Futures** tables must be joined by DATE)*

Is this possible in MySQL or I have to use scripting languages?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One method uses `join` and aggregation:

```
select i.date, i.index,
       max(case when f.name = 'Aug' then f.value end) as Aug,
       max(case when f.name = 'Sep' then f.value end) as Sep
from index i left join
     futures f
     on i.date = f.date
group by i.date, i.index;
```

This scales well but requires aggregating all the data.  An alternative uses two joins:

```
select i.date, i.index,
       faug.value as aug, fsep.value as sep
from index i left join
     futures faug
     on faug.date = i.date and faug.name = 'Aug' left join
     futures fsep
     on fsep.date = i.date and fsep. name = 'Sep';
```

Note that `index` is a SQL keyword so it is a bad name for a table.